# Python: Better to load dict and use or query sqlite database?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

I've got a database of ~10,000 rows and 30 columns. I run several processes at a time that currently query unique rows from the database ~100 times per minute each. Is it better to leave things as they are, and have them query each time, or would it be better to have each process load the database into a dict at the start and get values from that?

Also, I just started doing this. Will I run into any issues with multiple processes trying to query the same database at the same time?

Comment: I don't think you will face problem with multiple processes trying to query the same database at the same time. BTW we need to know if that columns contains e-mail addresses or `int`. Sqlite is pretty fast and if you are retrieving just a column you shouldn't have resource problems. Give me a scenario example and the problem you have

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Columns contain a mix of  ints and text. The query column is an int. 

I can't say that I have a problem. Just trying to do whatever is most efficient.

Comment: How can it possibly contain numbers and text if it's an `int`? `int` columns can only contain numbers. What is the scenario? Are you trying to retrieve accounts for users? Rendering images?